# Why does the value of pointer b does not change when value of pointer a is changed

Tags: c

Here's an example c code for that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char *a = "something";
    char *b;
    b = a;
    a = "example";
    printf("%s", b);

    return 0;
}
```

Now, why is `b`'s value still "something"?

Shouldn't it change?

Comment: No.  Why do you think `b` should change?  Consider `int i = 42; int j = i; i = 0;`.  Should `j` change?

Comment: @chux Because it points to a?

Comment: No - if `b` was a `char **b = &a` then yes...

Comment: But somewhere in other c code, I have seen both being *a and *b but they change

Comment: "Because it points to a" --> `b` points to `"something"`.  It does not point to `a`.

Comment: `b = a;` means that b points to the same address where a is pointing (say 123987). Then `a` changes its value to 654321. Why should b change? b still points to address 123987.

Comment: Wow idk that...

Comment: @Goion Huh? There is no deep copy here.

Comment: assignment is a thing that happens when the statement is executed, it doesn't set up a formula for future evaluation. E.g. `int c = 5; int d; d = c;  c = 6; printf("%d\n", d);` prints `5`

Comment: Simple spoken. After the assignment `=` you let b point to the same address like a. The value or data object at that memory address is the string "something". After that you change to where `a` points to, a new data object (the other string). However, `b` is untouched from that and still points to the other data object. If you really want to affect the change on both pointers please refer to @AKX  answer. This is different from pointers to "standard" values, where you may use pointers to e.g. change the values at the pointer addresses via dereferencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At very first: Even though legal in C, you shouldn't ever assign string literals to `char*`, that results far too easily in modifying the literal by accident, which invokes undefined behaviour. Make sure to assign to `char const*` only to avoid trouble (which got mandatory in C++ recently – for a good reason).

Then step by step:

`a = "something"` – there is somewhere in memory an array of `char` that contains the nine characters of the string plus a terminating null character. `a` is assigned the *address* of this array (this is what a pointer actually is, just the memory address of some object).

`b = a` *copies* `a` into `b`. As both are pointers, *only the address* is copied. The string itself remains unchanged.

`a = "example"` – again there's an array in memory containing the null-terminated string. Only `a` is assigned, `b` remains untouched – thus will continue to contain first string's address. `a` in contrast receives the second string's address.

Dry drawing that with a pencil on paper: `a` and `b`, e. g. in a circle, representing the pointers, and the two strings. Do the assignments by drawing an arrow to the text `"something"`. As `b` copies `a`, both `a` and `b` should now point to `"something"`.

Now do the re-assignment of `a` by etching its arrow and re-drawing it, pointing to `"example"` – where does `b` (still) point to?

The whole matter changes if you modify the array itself (again: don't modify the literal itself!):

```
char text[] = "something";
//       ^^ note: array; it is initialized by copying the string literal into,
//                size will be the size of the literal
char* a = text;
char* b = text;

// modify the array:
   *a = 'S';
// ^ note: dereferencing the pointer, i. e. modify what a points to!

printf("%s", b); // prints 'Something' as b still points to the same memory location as a
```

Comment: @Aconcagua Indeed the code generates said warnings in C++, and great example of difference between char[] and char*.

Answer (score 0):

b=a; means b points to the address where a points.
if the code was :

```
int main()
{    
    char *a = "something";
    char *b;
    a = "example";
    b = a;    
    printf("%s", b);    
    return 0;
}
```

the output would be `"example"`;
and if the the code was:

```
 int main()
    {
        char *a = "something";
        char **b;
        b = &a;
        a = "example";
        printf("%s", *b);
        return 0;
    }
```

The output would be `"example"`, because on this case b always point to the value in a and not the address.

Comment: Running & compiling perfectly for me. @DonSlowik

Comment: You need to change `printf("%s", b);` to `printf("%s", *b);` so it correctly prints the value of b. Otherwise it will just print some garbage.

Comment: Right, copying mistake, fixed. @Goion